# WinSock2 accept as slow as slowest clients?

Tags: windows, winsock, winsock2

I have a TCPServer using WinSock2. The logic is pretty simple.

whenever accept returns, put the new socket in a worker thread and handle the work there.

However there is something strange i noticed:
When i have clients with high latency connecting, and a client with low latency, accept will not return until the high latency clients are properly connected. My impression about the Syn-Queue was, that whatever is ready first is put into the accept-queue and returned to the application?

The high latency clients are simulated by a client application on a VM which has a set latency in it's adapter configuration. That client constantly connects, does work and disconnects.

The low latency client is simulated by a Client from the same machine as the server.

For listen i use a Backlog value of SOMAXCON from Winsock2.h

Anyone has an idea what's going on? Or did i just missunderstood how the Syn-/Acceptqueues work? I know they have the name Queue in it but i did not expect them to be FIFO.